# How to get the pivot table return the value together with the corresponding column

Tags: pandas, dataframe, indexing, pivot-table, multiple-columns

I have the following data frame :

| Loc1 | Loc2 | Month | Trips |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | b | 1 | 200 |
| a | b | 4 | 500 |
| a | b | 7 | 600 |
| c | d | 6 | 400 |
| c | d | 4 | 300 |

I need to find out for every route (Loc1 to Loc2) which month has the most trips and with the corresponding trips number .

I run some code but the output I get is as follows. How do I get the Trips column appear together.

| Loc1 | Loc2 | Month |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | b | 7 |
| c | d | 6 |

The code I used as below :
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
df = df[['Loc1','Loc2','Month','Trips']]

```
df = df.pivot_table(index = ['Loc1', 'Loc2'],
columns = 'Month',
values = 'Trips',)  
df = df.idxmax(axis = 1)
df = df.reset_index()
print(f"Each route's busiest month : \n {df.to_string()}")
```

Comment: Thanks for editing the column. This is my first time not sure how to do it.

Comment: your initial config was correct. My apologies. I think you can try : ``df.groupby(['Loc1', 'Loc2'], as_index=False).Month.max()``

Comment: Hi, Thanks, but the code returns error !

Comment: for the same data you shared? what's the error?

Comment: Hi Sammy, sorry for the late response. It returns attribute error !! Not sure probably I inserted wrongly. Anyway I got another solution as below which worked. Thanks very much for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to sort by Trips in descending order and get the first row per group

```
df.sort_values(by='Trips', ascending=False).groupby(['Loc1', 'Loc2'], as_index=False).first()
```

Or:

```
df.sort_values(by='Trips').groupby(['Loc1', 'Loc2'], as_index=False).last()
```

*NB. I couldn't run the code to test, but you get the general idea.*